# hide siblings of the element after this() method

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a simple accordion but I cant get open `dds` to close once a `dt` is clicked.

```
<dl>
    <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?</dt>
    <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat.</dd>
    <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?</dt>
    <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat.</dd>
    <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?</dt>
    <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat.</dd>
</dl>

$('dd').hide();

$('dt').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

I tried

```
$(this).next().siblings().hide();
$(this).next().toggle();
```

But then only the dd under the dt that was clicked stays open, and all others get hidden.

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: Not really, but there isn't really a question in there, but the issue is the lack of filtering in the siblings method, which should be `.siblings('dd').hide()` to avoid hiding everything.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xBsq4/1/

Comment: Yes, I guess the issue is filtering. Thank you for your time. I guess I was expecting it to target dds only because of next() (still learning jquery). Thanks again for good advice.

Comment: After putting it to the test your answer helps more than the other one (filtering with siblings). Please post it as your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Of course it does, the other answer will target any and all `dd` elements in the entire document. I'll post it!

Comment: Yea but that is not the issue, I can easily select only dds I want, the issue with the other answer is that it makes me a problem with slideToggle, whereas siblings doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`siblings()` will target any siblings regardless of tagName, so both `dd` and `dt` elements will be hidden.
You'll need to filter the siblings based on tagName to hide only the sibling `dd` elements:

```
$('dt').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next().toggle().siblings('dd').hide()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> "I cant get open dds to close once a dt is clicked."

If you want all the other ones closed when clicking on a new one, simply include your `hide()` event inside the click:

```
$('dd').hide();
$('dt').on('click', function() {
    $('dd').hide();
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/xBsq4/)

Although you could just use CSS for the initial `$('dd').hide();` instead: `dd { display:none; }`

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was overcomplicating it.